# Draw data from InputStream every fixed byte length?

Tags: java, inputstream

Given an InputStream, I want a tool where I call `next()`, the current execution blocks until 50 bytes have accumulated in the stream, at which point `next()` returns with a `byte[]` of length 50, containing the relevant data.

It was surprisingly difficult to find the right phrases on Google, which is why I am here.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want an `InputStream` that behaves this way, because you want the `next()` call to "return" the data to the code that is waiting, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You're totally right, I had it wrong in my head. Editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely consult the standard JDK library for excellent classes to read and write IO. But your requirement was rather interesting. You wanted an "iterator" kind of interface for the input stream. So, here is my attempt. Of course, some optimizations are possible, but hopefully it brings out the idea well. Let me know if this is what you're looking for. I admit that there is a subtle change to the contract in that the method `hasNext()` blocks on the underlying input stream. I hope that is alright.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

/** An attempt for:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817251/draw-data-from-inputstream-every-fixed-byte-length
 *  <b>This class is NOT thread safe.</b>
 * Created by kmhaswade on 3/5/16.
 */
public class InputStreamIterator extends BufferedInputStream implements Iterator<byte[]> {

    private final InputStream in;
    private final byte[] bytes;
    private int bytesRead;
    /**
     * Returns a buffered input stream that "iterates" over a given stream. Follows the decorator pattern.
     * @param in the input stream that should be buffered
     * @param n
     */
    public InputStreamIterator(InputStream in, int n) {
        super(in);
        this.in = in;
        if (n <=0 || n > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal value: " + n);
        bytes = new byte[n];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        try {
            bytesRead = super.read(this.bytes);
            if (bytesRead == -1) {
                this.close();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // could be handled better ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] next() {
        if (bytes.length == bytesRead)
            return bytes;
        else
            return Arrays.copyOf(bytes, bytesRead);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new RuntimeException("no way to push back yet");
    }

    @Override
    public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super byte[]> action) {
        throw new RuntimeException("not yet implemented");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStreamIterator itIn = new InputStreamIterator(System.in, 50);
        while (itIn.hasNext()) {
            byte[] bs = itIn.next();
            for (byte b : bs) {
                System.out.println("byte read: " + b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such tool in the JDK, but you can simply wrap your `InputStream` into a [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and call [`readFully(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully-byte:A-) on it:

```
InputStream is = // ...
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
byte[] bytes = new byte[50];
dis.readFully(bytes);
// "bytes" now contains exactly 50 bytes from the stream
```

To have a class with a `next()` method, implement the [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) interface and do the above internally.